# Sharing a common set of Examples across multiple Scenario Outlines in Specflow

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

Is is possible to share a common set of examples across multiple scenario outlines in Specflow without duplicating the set of examples for each outline?

e.g. excuse the noddy example, but here the `Examples` are repeated for each `Scenario Outline` and I want to know if it's possible to declare those `Examples` once and use them for each `Scenario Outline`?

```
Feature: Just an example about animals

Scenario Outline:
    Given an <animal>
    When something happens 
    Then this should be the outcome

    Examples:
    | animal |
    | Dog |
    | Cat |

Scenario Outline:
    Given an <animal>
    When something different happens
    Then this other thing should be the outcome

    Examples:
    | animal |
    | Dog |
    | Cat |
```

Comment: I'm curious about this myself, it would be very useful in the future to have this if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is not actually possible in SpecFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about SepcFlow, but we have done this in Cucumber where the Given step is shared in this instance.

I would expect SpecFlow to work in a the same way.

Comment: I don't quite follow, do you have an example? I found there is "Background" for doing something v close to what I want, but that doesn't support parameters (i.e. no "Background Outline") from what I can see?