# How to write step definition file of scenario outline feature in Cypress

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, cucumber, cypress, gherkin

I'm using Feature file below:

```
Scenario Outline: Admin can send invitations to any user roles 
    And Click on drop-down to select role <Role>

    Examples:
    |Role|
    |Admin|
    |Manager|
```

I'm trying to write a step definition file here, but none of them worked

**#1: Passing as parameters**... doesn't work

```
And('Click on drop-down to select role "([^"]*)"', (role) => {
    cy.get('.add-person__inputs--container > :nth-child(2) > .ui').contains(role).click()
```

[image]

**#2: Passing as string values**....doesn't work

```
And('Click on drop-down to select role {string}', (role_value) => {
cy.get(`.add-person__inputs--container > :nth-child(2) > .ui[value='${role_value}']`).click()
```

[image]

**Cypress result of #1 & #2**:

[image]

**#3**: also tried this and seems to have a better shot cos simply it gave me a different error LOL

```
And('Click on drop-down to select role {string}', (role_value) => {
cy.get('.add-person__inputs--container > :nth-child(2) > .ui').find(role_value).click()
```

**Cypress result for #3**:
[image]

**HTML** for the page I'm testing, I'm trying to get those highlighted values from dropdown items but it has no id or name in front of each item

And I got `cy.get('.add-person__inputs--container > :nth-child(2) > .ui')` from Cypress selector

[image]

**HTML tags**

```
<div class="add-person__inputs--container" style="" xpath="1"><div class="field "><span class="login-form__inputs-container--title">Email</span><div class="ui large input login-form__inputs-container--input"><input name="email" placeholder="Add email address" autocomplete="new-password" type="email" value=""></div></div><div class="add-person__description--container"><span class="login-form__inputs-container--title">Role</span><div name="role" role="listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="true" class="ui active visible fluid selection dropdown add-person__dropdown" tabindex="0"><div class="text" role="alert" aria-live="polite">Viewer</div><i aria-hidden="true" class="chevron down icon"></i><div class="visible menu transition"><div role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="true" class="active selected item" style="pointer-events: all;">Viewer</div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;">Grower</div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;">Manager</div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;">Admin</div></div></div></div>
```

please bear in mind I'm very new to coding but I think the issue is either step definition file or css selector... :(

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks in step call missing quotes, try as blow:

```
   And Click on drop-down to select role "<Role>"
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer but I've tried sting and parameter.... but I think the issue is with either step definition file or CSS selector..... I've updated with more details, please take another look when you have time :)

Answer (score 1):

In Example: change it to string. This worked for me:

Scenario Outline: Admin can send invitations to any user roles
And click on dropdown to select role.

```
Examples:
|Role|
|"Admin"|
|"Manager"|
```

and

```
('Click on drop-down to select role {string}', (role_value) => {
cy.get(`.add-person__inputs--container > :nth-child(2) > .ui[value='${role_value}']`).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked for me:

In the feature file:

```
And Click on drop-down to select role "<Role>"
```

In the step definition file:

```
And(/^Click on drop-down to select role "(.*?)"$/, (role) => {
    cy.get('.add-person__inputs--container > :nth-child(2) > .ui').contains(role).click()
});
```